# Pop up a message or run a program on remote windows 7 computer so currently logged on user can see it

Tags: windows-7, remote, pstools, at

How can you pop up a message or run a program on remote computer so the currently logged on user can see it.

We have done this on WinXP, but these don't work with Win7.

```
at.exe \\computername time /interactive message.vbs
```

(time is hh:mm at least a minute in the future)

```
psexec.exe \\computername -I message.vbs
```

To test it you could replace message.vbs with Notepad.exe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netsend messages have been removed from Windows 7.

One way I have found to do this without installing 3rd party software is to leverage the remote shutdown commands:

```
shutdown -m \\computername -r -f -c "MESSAGE" -t 120
shutdown -m \\computername -a
```

The first command pops a message up, and will begin the shutdown in 120 seconds, the second command will cancel the remote shutdown (-a).

Test this on something that does not matter first!

Comment: This does help with the desire to pop up a message. In windows 7 it pops up a small yellow box on the bottom right off the systems tray and goes away after a few seconds. In XP however its a nice big pop up message that wouldn't be missed. I was hoping to also to see if I was able to launch a program remotely that would appear for the remote user. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank's that helps on few windows 7 boxes, however, it is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

by vbscript:

```
dim WMIObj, strHost, intProcessID

on error resume next

strHost = "remotehost.domain.com"

set WMIObj = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strHost & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
if IsObject(WMIObj) then
    WMIObj.Create "cmd.exe /C msg * ""ha-ha-ha""", null, null, intProcessID
end if

set WMIObj = nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be doable with the `msg`. Something like

`msg <username> /SERVER:<servername> <message`

Answer (score 2):

The following command works with XP and 7 initiated from 2003 server:

```
at \\remotecomputer time /interactive msg remoteuser /SERVER:remotecomputer This is the message
```

The `remotecomputer` is the computer where the message should appear and the `remoteuser` is the user logged into the remote computer (user who should see the message).

To clear all at commands on the remote computer use:

```
at \\remotecomputer /delete /yes
```

Use this before the "message" at.

Answer (score 2):

For the xp users
at.exe \computername time /interactive message.vbs

when on windows 7, try
SCHTASKS /Create  /SC DAILY  /TN my1stschtask /TR message.vbs /ST hh:mm:ss /SD dd/mm/yyyy

where 
my1stschtask is any scheduled task name (referenced when need to delete the task)
like AT number id to delete task need a reference

In dos command line, schtasks /?  to search out the relevant info

Answer (score -1):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


set msg1=This is a message from Information Services. Please contact IT Support on nnnnn as soon as possible to resolve a Windows Update issue on this machine, quoting Reference Fnnnnnnn. Thank you


msg /SERVER:[Computer Host name] */TIME:300 %msg1

%
```

Comment: This for Windows 10 :)