# Send message to all logged in clients in active directory from windows server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

Hello I'm wondering how i can notify ALL my users that is currently logged in on their client computers that there will be a maintainance and such? the msg command does not work for me i've tried.

Additional question:
Can i force a user to log off from a computer so it logs off immidiatly?

Wish you could have a panel where you could see the active sessions on what client and what user and just right click to log off and alot other stuff

Comment: First part possible duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/419301/pop-up-a-message-or-run-a-program-on-remote-windows-7-computer-so-currently-logg

Comment: @Drifter104 Both parts are actually addressed in the marked answer of the question you're linking to.

Comment: @notjustme That would shutdown/restart but OP said log off

Comment: @Drifter104 Oh right, my bad...

Comment: Can you make that run commands on ALL pc at the same time instead of specirfying that individual computer @Drifter104

Comment: @TobiasKarlsen I imagine you could run it inside PowerShell so I don't see why not. Either with a get-adcomputer (filter) or import-csv

Comment: Any Ideas of some third party software?